# Showing all Users who are not in a group on AD

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of all users who are not in an AD group.

Group is All Email Users

I have tried this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties memberof | Where-Object {!($_.memberof -like "*all email*")} | measure
```

but it doesn't filter out correctly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the event that there are nested groups as members of the "all email" group, I added the `-recursive` switch for `get-adGroupMember`.

My process would be to collect all the users that are currently in the group, collect all the users that exist, then use the `Compare-Object` to filter the users not found in both groups (meaning the users that are not members of the "all email" group).

```
$usersInGroup = get-adGroupMember -identity <full dn of group> -recursive
$usersAll = get-adUsers
$usersNotInGroup = Compare-Object -referenceObject $usersInGroup -differenceObject $usersAll | 
    where-Object {$_.sideIndicator -eq "=>"}
```

Because the `$usersNotInGroup` is collected from the `Compare-Object` output, you won't have the rich AD object that was collected with `get-adUsers` (if memory serves, you'll have either the samAccountName or the full DN). This *should* be enough to get results from the Active Directory cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

The memberof property will likely return a string array, so you'd have to iterate through all the strings (different groups) to determine if the group doesn't exist in their memberof. That approach doesn't solve the problem of groups that are members of other groups, etc. etc. however.

My approach?

1) Grab all members of that All Email Users group. There are solutions on the net for how to iterate the group-members of that group (if any) to get the *real* members. Their user names should be stored in a string[]. This shouldn't be too hard, but I don't know how experienced you are w/ powershell either.

2)Grab all users from AD. Also store their user names in a string[].

3) Use the `diff` cmdlet on the two string arrays, which will provide you with the items (user names in this case) that exist in one [] but not the other. diff basically works like this:

```
diff $arUsers1 $arUsers2
```